Finding 2 or more matches of data_frames according to values of a specific column
I have a list of data frames and I want to find the match between dataframes such that in each data frame there is a column called "RMS", so I want to know if two or more data frames with the same sequence of RMS within a range between +5 and - 5 as follows:
  Data_Frame 1
    RMS    
0   55.6
1   70.9
2   91
3   36 

A good match would be like
   Data_Frame 2
    RMS    
0   60.6 ~ 51.6
1   75.9 ~ 65.9
2   95 ~ 85 
3   41 ~ 31   

I have tried the following code:
def find_matches(df_list, tolerance=5):
    matches = []
    
    for i, df1 in enumerate(df_list):
        for j, df2 in enumerate(df_list):
            if i != j:
                for rms_value in df1['RMS']:
                    matched_values = df2[(df2['RMS'] >= rms_value - tolerance) & (df2['RMS'] <= rms_value + tolerance)]
                    if not matched_values.empty:
                        matches.append((f'dataframe-{i+1}', rms_value, f'dataframe-{j+1}', matched_values['RMS'].tolist()))
    
    return matches

# Find matches
matches = find_matches(name_of_list_containing_data_frames, tolerance=5)

However, the function returns  matches if for example data_frame2 has only one value of RMS  (+/-5) a RMS value in data_frame1.
I need not just one value but also sequence of the RMS values in data_frame1 to be +/- 5 of the same sequence of RMS values in data_frame2.

You could try something like the following
from itertools import combinations

def find_matches(dfs, tolerance=5):
    return [
        (df1, df2) for df1, df2 in combinations(dfs, 2)
        if df1['RMS'].sub(df2['RMS']).abs().le(tolerance).all()
    ]

or, a bit more like in your code
from itertools import combinations

def find_matches(dfs, tolerance=5):
    return [
        (f"dataframe {i+1}", f"dataframe {j+1}")
        for i, j in combinations(range(len(dfs)), 2)
        if dfs[i]['RMS'].sub(dfs[j]['RMS']).abs().le(tolerance).all()
    ]


itertools.combinations to extract unique combinations of dataframes/indicees (the problem is symetric, so no need to process combinations twice).
df1['RMS'].sub(df2['RMS']).abs().le(tolerance).all() checks if the absolute difference between the resp. RMS columns is less or equal to the tolerance for all corresponding rows.

The result for the example
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame({"RMS": [55.6, 70.9, 91, 36]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"RMS": [56.6, 71.9, 92, 37]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"RMS": [65.6, 70.9, 91, 36]})  # first item is outlier
]

would be [('dataframe 1', 'dataframe 2')] (second version).

If you want to find larger combinations then you could try
def find_matches(dfs, tolerance=5, k=2):
    matching_pairs = {
        (i, j) for i, j in combinations(range(len(dfs)), 2)
        if dfs[i]['RMS'].sub(dfs[j]['RMS']).abs().le(tolerance).all()
    }
    if k == 2:
        return [(f"dataframe {i+1}", f"dataframe {j+1}") for i, j in matching_pairs]
    matches = []
    for combo in combinations(range(len(dfs)), k):
        if all(pair in matching_pairs for pair in combinations(combo, 2)):
            matches.append(tuple(f"dataframe {i+1}" for i in combo))
    return matches

with k the number of dataframes a match should contain (the 3 in the comment). Match means: the column RMS of all dataframes df1 and df2 in the match differs at most by tolerance.
Or, if you want all subsets:
def find_matches(dfs, tolerance=5):
    matching_pairs = {
        (i, j) for i, j in combinations(range(len(dfs)), 2)
        if dfs[i]['RMS'].sub(dfs[j]['RMS']).abs().le(tolerance).all()
    }
    matches = [(f"dataframe {i+1}", f"dataframe {j+1}") for i, j in matching_pairs]
    for k in range(3, len(dfs) + 1):
        for combo in combinations(range(len(dfs)), k):
            if all(pair in matching_pairs for pair in combinations(combo, 2)):
                matches.append(tuple(f"dataframe {i+1}" for i in combo))
    return matches


Thank you very much for your answer, it works well this way for 1 match (two dataframes). However, if I need more than 1 match e.g., 3 data frames should I adjust the code as follows?
´´´
def find_matches(dfs, tolerance=5):
return [
(f"dataframe {i+1}", f"dataframe {j+1}", f"dataframe {k+1}" )
for i, j, k in combinations(range(len(dfs)), 3)
if dfs[i]['RMS(MPa)'].sub(dfs[j]['RMS(MPa)']).sub(dfs[k]['RMS(MPa)']).abs().le(tolerance).all()
]
´´´´

@Abboud Not sure I understand this fully, but you could check my edit.
